# EF Core db first, Scaffold-DBContext not bringing one of the table

Tags: entity-framework

There are two tables, and there is a many-to-many relationship between them. User and UserGroups (which is mapping table) and Groups table. So a user can be in multiple groups and a group can have multiple users.

However, when I Scaffold, EF is not bringing the UserGroups table. Is it expected? Here is the context snippet for User table:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("User");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.AccessLevelId, "IX_User_AccessLevelId");

            entity.Property(e => e.Azid).HasColumnName("AZID");
            entity.Property(e => e.Department).HasDefaultValueSql("(N'')");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.AccessLevel).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(d => d.AccessLevelId);

            entity.HasMany(d => d.Groups).WithMany(p => p.Users)
                .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                    "UserGroup",
                    r => r.HasOne<Group>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("GroupId"),
                    l => l.HasOne<User>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("UserId"),
                    j =>
                    {
                        j.HasKey("UserId", "GroupId");
                        j.ToTable("UserGroups");
                        j.HasIndex(new[] { "GroupId" }, "IX_UserGroups_GroupId");
                    });
        });
```

as we can see EF recognized the relations, but it didn't created model class for UserGroup. If it is expected then how can I achieve below requirements:

```
            return await (from u in _context.Users
                          join ug in _context.UserGroup on u.UserId equals ug.UserId
                          join g in _context.Groups on ug.GroupId equals g.GroupId
                          where u.Azid == userAZID && g.Name.ToLower() == "admin"
                          select u.UserId
                          ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The requirement is to check if user exist in Admin group or not.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using EF6 or EF Core? If so, what verison?

Comment: All versions of EF (and maybe EFCore?) that I'm aware of will elide an entity-class for many-to-many linking tables when those tables consist of _only_ FKs with no data-members of their own. The quick-and-dirty workaround is to add a dummy column to the linking table.

Comment: EF core 6 and later does not add an Entity for many to many tables. You can use EF core Power Tools to bring it back bur you do not need it